# The testcase execution order differed between testng.xml and maven surefire

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

Triggered testng.xml from eclipse, and worked as expected (the order of the classes were as given in testng.xml). On triggering the same using maven surefire from command line (mvn clean , mvn install), the order of the classes differed. Example, maven triggers tc01 of Class8 instead of tc01 of class1. This confirms that the  execution order of classes between testng and sure fire differed.

Will surefire ignore the order followed by testng.xml ? If so any flag to force sure fire to follow as given in testng.xml ? After investing good amount of time and analysis to design the suite (testng.xml), I hope the maven would be able to trigger testng.xml with the way it exists. Did try few of the options available online but could not help.

Thank you in advance.

Below are the testng.xml and sure fire data.

```
testng.xml
<test thread-count="5" name="REGRESSION Test" preserve-order="true" enabled="true">
<class name="com.org.ipac.Login.LoginPage" />


pom.xml
 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <suiteXmlFile>C:\trunk\Hyd2019\Selenium\IPAC\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </properties>
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Regression</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20</version>
                        <configuration>
                             <!-- <runOrder>filesystem</runOrder>-->
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>TIB_ip-test-ipac_${project.version}_win_x86_64</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: First you should upgrade the maven-surefire-plugin version to the most recent, because you are using a version wich is of 2017!... Check here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/. And most important why have you defined all this within a profile?

Answer (score 0):

Updating testng version to 7.8.0, in pom dependency, fixed the issue.

```
Before:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
After:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```